# Bootstrap glyphicon changes icon when I copy it on localhost

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I use bootstrap to display a glyphicon icon, the online link works fine, when I copy the bootstrap.min.css locally, the icon is not working properly !!!

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
    <p>Search icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></p>
```

gives : [image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<p>Search icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></p>
```

gives : [image]

I want to keep the css locally to reduce loading time

Comment: The path to the icon is now incorrect. Use the inspector to resolve.

Comment: @ScottSimpson Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the poroblem was bootstrap.min.css points to `fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2` , `fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff` and `fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf` in the same path. so I have to copy them too :)
[image]
Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you referenced the right path for your local copy of Bootstrap? Your href is pointing to bootstrap.css.You are talking about bootstrap.min.css.

Check the developer to see if it recognizes bootstrap. That should provide some information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download complete package's of bootstrap on this link http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#downloadand put into local-host folder

then you can link stylesheet like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1/xxxxxxx/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

i think this may help you